# Mongodb-aggregation do sum and addtoSet work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like this:

```
{"_id":"xxx","user_id":111,"time":14142342234,"amount":1000,"category":["A","B","C"]}
{"_id":"xxx","user_id":111,"time":14142342234,"amount":1000,"category":["B","C"]}
{"_id":"xxx","user_id":222,"time":14142342234,"amount":1000,"category":["A","B","C"]}
```

each user have multi record belong to different time.
my job is find out top 100 user which have max amount sum and the category size in a certain time range.

so I have to `$group` by `user_id`, `$sum` the amount but, how do I get the category set for each user? And if I want to sort by category size?

Comment: So what would be the correct category sizes, and why? What have you tried? What do you think you might have to do? These are all fairly simple things if you apply yourself for a moment. Perhaps you should show what you tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thanks for remind ,I had try to use $group and $addToSet, but could not get result

Comment: So what else did you try? I only see a comment below where you seem to be confusing [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) as an "update operator" with [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) of the aggregation framework. These are of course two different things. If you want the "set" of combined arrays, it should be a "no brainer" as there is *"the most common thing you need to do with arrays when aggregating their content"*. If you just apply a little thinking here it's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting exercise for learning. I've made the aggregation pipeline you can find below. It is compound by 3 stages:

1. **$match**: To determine the time interval
2. **$group**: To aggregate the *amount* field *category* and *category* list size
3. **$sort**: To order by the generated fields *total_amount* and *categories_size*

I hope it does help:

```
db.col.aggregate([
           {  
   $match:{  
      $and:[  
         {  
            'time':{  
               $gt:14142342233
            }
         },
         {  
            'time':{  
               $lt:14142342235
            }
         }
      ]
   }
},
{  
   $group:{  
      _id:'$user_id',
      total_amount:{  
         $sum:'$amount'
      },
      categories:{
        $addToSet:'$category'
      },
      categories_size:{  
         $sum:{  
            $size:'$category'
         }
      }
   }
},
{  
   $sort:{  
      total_ammount:1,
      categories_size:1
   }
}])
```

An additional advice is: If you're going to work with MongoDB in the future, this kind of exercises are extremely useful for the day to day tasks with MongoDB, so try to find resources such as courses or even this site to keep practising.

Regards

Comment: thanks , however I want to get a set of category for each user.
`{
 '_id':'$user_id',
 'amount':{'$sum':'$amount'},
 'categorys':{'$addToSet':{'$each':'$category'}}
}`
but this did not work.

Comment: I don't think you have event try my answer. And much less trying to understand it.

Comment: Also, it's completely useless to just say "it doesn't work". You need to provide the expected result versus the actual result. Only in that case we would be able to help.